# $f, f|f| \in L^{1} (\mathbb R) \cap C_{0} (\mathbb R) \implies |f| \in H_{1} (\mathbb R)$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $f \  \text{and} \ f|f|\in L^{1}(\mathbb R).$ Then, clearly, $|f|\in L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ and therefore by [Plancheral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), we get, $\widehat{|f|} \in L^{2}(\mathbb R).$ Also, assume, $f, |f|f, \hat{f}, \widehat{f|f|} \in L^{1}(\mathbb R) \cap C_{0}(\mathbb R).$

**My Question**: Can we expect $|f|\in H_{1}(\mathbb R)=\{ f\in \mathcal{S'}(\mathbb R): (1+|\xi|^{2})^{1/2}\hat{f}\in L^{2}(\mathbb R) \}$ ([Sobolev spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) ), Or, we we can  produce a counter example ?

(If we put, additional condition, $|(\widehat{|f|}(\xi))| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + |\xi|^{2}}},  \ (\xi \in \mathbb R)$, then, certainly, by definition of sobolev space,  it will follows; so is this condition necessary ?)

**Motivation**: Actually, I want to show: $\widehat{|f|}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R);$ so it sufficient to show, $|f|\in H_{1}$. If there is other way, I would like to have your suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any non identically zero function, such that $f,\hat f\in C_0(\mathbb R)?$

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(t)= 1- |t|$ for $|t|\leq 1$ and $f(t)= 0$ for $|t| >1.$

Comment: I said both $f$ and $\hat f$ to be in $C_0(\mathbb R)$. Do you know such an example? Because you have this requirement...

Comment: The Fourier transform of the above triangle function will be; $\frac{(\sin\pi t)^{2}} {(\pi t)^{2}}$

Comment: If a function has compact support, then its Fourier transform is an entire analytic function! (Paley-Wiener Theorem) - So your assumptions, only the identically zero function satisfies!

Comment: No, I am not assuming $f$ has a compact support; what all I am assuming is it will continuous and vanish at infinity; in the original question;

Comment: If $f(x)= e^{-x^{2}}$; then $\hat{f}(\xi)= (\pi)^{1/2} e^{-\pi^{2} \xi^{2}}$. (The Fourier transform of the Gaussian is Gaussian)

Comment: Just to clarify the preceding exchange in comments: for some people $C_0$ means "compactly supported", for others it means "vanishing at infinity". A question involving $C_0$ notation should disambiguate its meaning.